# How to check the java data type of an element in a custom collection?

Tags: java, max-msp-jitter

```
Object ele=a.get(i);
if(ele instanceof java.lang.Integer){//cast to integer:
    print("found Int");
}else{ //cast to string:
    print("found: "+ele.getClass());
}
//prints: found: class com.cycling74.max.Atom$IntAtom
```

This is part of a larger chunk of code but this is the relevant part. I need to know how to check the type of an element in the Atom class by [cycling74](http://www.le-son666.com/software/pdj/api/com/cycling74/max/Atom.html).

```
if(ele instanceof com.cycling74.max.Atom$IntAtom)
//ERROR: com.cycling74.max.Atom.IntAtom has private access in com.cycling74.max.Atom
```

Any ideas??
Thanks a lot - this is really doing my head in!!

Comment: If the class is declared `private` you can't do an `instanceof` outside of `com.cycling74.max.Atom` class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is possible without making `IntAtom` public although it is a bit hacky.

First you need to get a reference to the private inner `IntAtom` class:

```
public class SomeClass {
  public static final Class<?> INT_ATOM_CLASS;
  static {
    Class<?> [] innerClasses = Atom.class.getDeclaredClasses();
    Class<?> intAtomClass = null;
    for (Class<?> klass : innerClasses) {
      if (klass.getSimpleName().equals("IntAtom")) {
        intAtomClass = klass;
        break;
      }
    }
    INT_ATOM_CLASS = intAtomClass;
  }
}
```

Then to do the instanceof check:

```
if (SomeClass.INT_ATOM_CLASS.isAssignableFrom(ele.getClass())) {
   // do stuff
}
```

Javadoc for [Class.isAssignableFrom(Class c);](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html)

Answer (score 1):

I think you'll have to either make IntAtom public, or provide a public function in Atom that can verify whether an object is an IntAtom or not.  Right now the class definition can't be compared against because it's private to Atom.

Comment: Hmm, thanks @roberttdev It sounds complicated. I dont have access to the Atom class tho. It's an API built into MaxMSP software. Also, if I did have access,I wouldnt know where to begin doing that as I'm brand new to java! (this is my first project!). Is there any hacky workaround I might be able to try??

Comment: The only thing I can think of is to subclass Atom and make the change yourself.  It's not pretty.. but I don't know how else you can access that private class.  Double check the API to make sure they don't offer something for this first.

Comment: your subclassing solution won't help as private classes isn't inherited by the subclasses.

Comment: it is *possible* to do it without making IntAtom public, although not necessarily advisable.  See my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot fellas - it seems the Atom class has a method somewhere called isInt() that can check the built in datatype. I wouldnt have looked for it had you guys not got back so I really appreciate the help!

Comment: This should have been a comment, i.e. don't post comments on answer sections.